# SaaS SMTP Mail routing

Tags: email, routes, smtp, saas

Mail routing is an important aspect of a SaaS application. Maintaining a high throughput email infrastructure (prevent spamming, grey/white/black listing etc) is quite complex. We are building a B2B SaaS app which will be used by our clients to send mails to their clients (outbound only). We want to keep our infrastructure thin by outsourcing mail. We are looking at the best way to send SMTP outbound mails without worrying about blacklisting / throughput and such ? Any 3rd parties you can recommend that our Php program can plug-in and route mails ? Pls advise.

Answer (score 2):

AWS provides a Simple Email Service which will help and includes PHP SDK.

http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

Look at Port25's software named "PowerMTA". It may be what you need.
Or if you want it as a service here's a good comparison of most popular options: http://blog.ombud.com/2012/05/21/price-comparison-transactional-email-delivery